# how to put an non removable footer credit

Tags: javascript, php, footer

I want to put an footer credit in my website template Like :-
    My Website Name 
Is it possible by any javascrip or php so that no one can edit or delete or no one can hide it by commenting it .if they do so , they should be redirected to my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript, this would be posibble, but the client could remove the javascript too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function()
{
 if($("#mycredit").attr("href")!="http://www.keyyard.blogspot.com/")
 {
  window.location.href="link_to_your_site";
 }

});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks sir . 
how to use this code ? Please Sir ,write in detail that where should i place this code and what div structure i have to make for footer credit ?

Comment: and i will host the js from another server and with another name so that it will be more complicated for the client to reach there

Comment: Sir please give me a detailed description , how to use this javascript  for footer credit .
Thanks in advance sir

Comment: No div structure... Only a link with id `mycredit`. You can embed this js where you want, but after Jquery embed. you have to replace the url in the code with that, where the link should point to and instead of redirect put any code you want executed in the case, the link was removed

Comment: Sir I am not very good at coding .But i want that if the link was removed or changed or commented , then the site should redirect to an specific url (example :- to my portfolio page ). Can you please give code for that sir ...

Comment: @Hussain what do you mean by 'hosting the JS on another server'? Will your template just link to your JS on your server? If so, all the customer has to do is remove the link. FYI, Eddy's answer is using jQuery in addition to JavaScript.

Comment: @EddynandFuchs Thanks sir , this script worked for me but there is only one thing left , 
example :- <a id="mycredit" href="site url">Site Name </a>

the javascript is checking the 'id' and the url in 'href' and if it is not present then it will redirect to our desired website but the script is not checking the text written between <a> ... </a> tag (example:- Site Name ) so that anyone can change the site name in credit .
Please add code so that no one can change the text written between <a>  </a> tag .

Comment: Thanks @EddynandFuchs and DA for replying and Eddyand's answer worked for me . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving them the template code and markup, then no, there's no practical way to do this, as they have the code and markup at their disposal to change.

This is a legal issue rather than a technology issue. The license/contract should stipulate that the credit must remain.

Comment: but is this possible by an javascript code , so that if any one changes or deletes the html code of my footer credit , then it is checked by javascript and the site is redirected to my desired link ?

Comment: Yes, you could write JS that does that. And then the person that bought your templates could simply delete or over-ride that bit of JavaScript.

Comment: I will try to hide that js file code . Please tell me if there is any js code like this which checks my footer credit's html code and if there is any change in my footer credit or if my footer credit is deleted , then the site should be redirected to my desired website

Comment: I have googled for this and i came across a blog post but it is not working , may be there is any minor problem in that code , Please see this and fix this if you can . This is the Post link :- 
http://keyyard.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-add-non-removable-credit-link-in_11.html

Comment: I can't in good faith do that, since it won't actually work for your needs. Anyone that knows how to use Firebug could easily circumvent any obfuscation tricks in your JS. That said, if you are having trouble with specific code, I suggest you post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Μy approach to the issue is shown to this [**[fiddle][1](http://jsfiddle.net/synaxipalaiochoriou/eetg7w7p/)**](http://jsfiddle.net/synaxipalaiochoriou/eetg7w7p/)

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

    $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#footer-post').length == 1) 
// check if <a> exists in id="footer-post" and changes <a> address and class
      {
        $('#footer-post a').prop('href', 'http://synaxipalaiochoriou.blogspot.gr/').prop('class', 'footer-3').text('Σύναξη Νέων Παλαιοχωρίου');
      }

      if ($('#footer-post').length >= 1 && $('a.footer-3').length == 0) { 
// if link is erased it creates a new one in the same div
        $('<a>', {
          class: 'footer-3',
          text: 'Σύναξη Νέων Παλαιοχωρίου',
          href: 'http://synaxipalaiochoriou.blogspot.gr/',
        }).appendTo('#footer-post');
      }

      if ($('#footer-post').length == 0 && $('a.footer-3').length == 0) { 
// if div and link are erased it shows an alert and load yahoo
        alert('Link has been erased')
        window.location.href="https://gr.yahoo.com/";
      }
    });
        //]]>
        </script>
```

where:

```
<div id="footer-post">
<a class='footer-3' href="http://google.com">google</a>
</div>
```

last but not least, use "javascriptobfuscator.com" to obfuscate your script so that people do not tamper/erase it easily. The result of the script would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[var _0x7f0e=["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x23\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x2D\x70\x6F\x73\x74","\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\x20\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\x20\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD","\x74\x65\x78\x74","\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73","\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x2D\x33","\x70\x72\x6F\x70","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x73\x79\x6E\x61\x78\x69\x70\x61\x6C\x61\x69\x6F\x63\x68\x6F\x72\x69\x6F\x75\x2E\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x73\x70\x6F\x74\x2E\x67\x72\x2F","\x23\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x2D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x20\x61","\x61\x2E\x66\x6F\x6F\x74\x65\x72\x2D\x33","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x54\x6F","\x3C\x61\x3E","\x4C\x69\x6E\x6B\x20\x68\x61\x73\x20\x62\x65\x65\x6E\x20\x65\x72\x61\x73\x65\x64","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x73\x3A\x2F\x2F\x77\x77\x77\x2E\x67\x6F\x6F\x67\x6C\x65\x2E\x67\x72\x2F","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"];$(document)[_0x7f0e[16]](function(){if($(_0x7f0e[1])[_0x7f0e[0]]== 1){$(_0x7f0e[9])[_0x7f0e[6]](_0x7f0e[7],_0x7f0e[8])[_0x7f0e[6]](_0x7f0e[4],_0x7f0e[5])[_0x7f0e[3]](_0x7f0e[2])};if($(_0x7f0e[1])[_0x7f0e[0]]>= 1&& $(_0x7f0e[10])[_0x7f0e[0]]== 0){$(_0x7f0e[12],{class:_0x7f0e[5],text:_0x7f0e[2],href:_0x7f0e[8]})[_0x7f0e[11]](_0x7f0e[1])};if($(_0x7f0e[1])[_0x7f0e[0]]== 0&& $(_0x7f0e[10])[_0x7f0e[0]]== 0){alert(_0x7f0e[13]);window[_0x7f0e[14]][_0x7f0e[7]]= _0x7f0e[15]}})//]]></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A not good way would be to call their site by a cronjob, analyzing it's footer and look out. To redirect them to your site, you have  to make a php file on your theme, wich edits itsself. But this php could be removed and your only way to stop them is to sue them, but this only works, if your license is right.

Comment: I have googled for this and i came across a blog post but it is not working , may be there is any minor problem in that code , Please see this and fix this if you can . This is the Post link :- 
http://keyyard.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-add-non-removable-credit-link-in_11.html

Comment: i think, the div mustn't have the id #mycredit. only the link... And Watch out, the js could be removed...